# Need assistance with very simple C++ for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
for( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )
{
    cout << setw(2) << i << setw(10) << ( i <= 5 ? cout <<" = Chipotle" : cout << " = McDonalds" ) << endl;
}
```

So, I expected the output to be:

```
 0 = Chipotle
 1 = Chipotle
 2 = Chipotle
 3 = Chipotle
 4 = Chipotle
 5 = Chipotle
 6 = McDonalds
 7 = McDonalds
 8 = McDonalds
 9 = McDonalds
10 = McDonalds
```

(Don't worry about the setw formatting)

Instead, my IDE gave me:

```
 = Chipotle 0  0x602208                                                                                                             
 = Chipotle 1  0x602208                                                                                                             
 = Chipotle 2  0x602208                                                                                                             
 = Chipotle 3  0x602208                                                                                                             
 = Chipotle 4  0x602208                                                                                                             
 = Chipotle 5  0x602208                                                                                                             
 = McDonalds 6  0x602208                                                                                                            
 = McDonalds 7  0x602208                                                                                                            
 = McDonalds 8  0x602208                                                                                                            
 = McDonalds 9  0x602208                                                                                                            
 = McDonalds10  0x602208
```

Where did I went wrong?

Comment: hint: cout << cout in ` ( i <= 5 ? cout <<" = Chipotle" : cout << " = McDonalds" )`

Comment: don't put the cout inside cout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You display `cout` itself, remove `cout` in ternary operator:

```
cout << setw(2) << i << setw(10) << ( i <= 5 ? " = Chipotle" : " = McDonalds" ) << endl
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to cout a cout.

```
( i <= 5 ? cout <<" = Chipotle" : cout << " = McDonalds" )
```

becomes either

```
cout <<" = Chipotle" 
//or 
cout << " = McDonalds"
```

So you are trying to do

```
cout << setw(2) << i << setw(10) << cout <<" = Chipotle" 
//or
cout << setw(2) << i << setw(10) << cout <<" = McDonalds"
```

Which is incorrect.  You need to change you code to

```
( i <= 5 ? " = Chipotle" : " = McDonalds" )
```

Which will expand to

```
cout << setw(2) << i << setw(10) << " = Chipotle" 
//or
cout << setw(2) << i << setw(10) << " = McDonalds"
```

Answer (score 1):

When `i <= 5` is true, this

```
cout << i << ( i <= 5 ? cout <<" = Chipotle" : cout << " = McDonalds" ) << endl
```

evaluates like this:

```
cout << i << (cout << " = Chipotle") << endl
```

I omitted the `setw` manipulators here to make the code easier to read,
which would affect spacing in the result 
but makes no difference otherwise.
The result is the same as this sequence of operations:

```
cout << " = Chipotle"; // the thing in `()` gets evaluated first
cout << i;
cout << cout; // because (cout << " = Chipotle") evaluates to cout
cout << endl;
```

which is exactly what you see for the first few lines.
`cout` itself is printed out as `0x602208`.
After that you get `McDonalds` instead of `Chipotle`.

If you just write `cout` once, at the left end of your output expression,
you will get the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to write cout again inside the if condition you have written using the ?: operators. Just place the string what you want to print without the cout

Comment: "the if condition you have written using the ?: operators" = ternary operator ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is more precise and readable approach.

```
for( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )
{
    cout << setw(2) << i << setw(10) ;
    if(i<= 5)
    {
        cout <<" = Chipotle"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " = McDonalds" << endl;
    }
}
```